# How to get partials from a Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I would like to be able to extract from an Handlebars template all partials referenced into it.

Something like this :

```
var template = Handlebars.compile('<p>Hello {{> mypartial}}</p>');
console.log(template.partials); // <- i want to print ['mypartial']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a while before finding the awnser to that, but it was deep in handlebars doc :
https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/blob/master/docs/compiler-api.md#ast-visitor

If you create a class ImportScanner to overload PartialStatement, like in the doc :

```
var Visitor = Handlebars.Visitor;

function ImportScanner() {this.partials = [];}
ImportScanner.prototype = new Visitor();

ImportScanner.prototype.PartialStatement = function(partial) {
  this.partials.push(partial.name.original);
  Visitor.prototype.PartialStatement.call(this, partial);
};
```

You then can use it to get all partials from a parsed template :

```
var ast = Handlebars.parse('<p>Hello {{> mypartial}}</p>');
var scanner = new ImportScanner();
scanner.accept(ast);
console.log(scanner.partials); // <= print ['mypartial']
```

But it only works for first level partials. If 'mypartial' contains an other partial you wont find it.